# How to change Shotwell keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, shotwell

I want to edit quickly lots of pictures in Shotwell. It already has some shortcuts, like <kbd>]</kbd> for Rotate. However, I work on a Qwertz keyboard, where <kbd>]</kbd> is typed as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>, which means I have to hit two non-home-row buttons with the same hand. It is slow, awkward, and bad for the tendons.

I would like to map it to some easy key like <kbd>R</kbd>. Is there a config file somewhere which I can edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've had other complaints about the rotate key shortcuts. They [[image] will be changed back](http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/2700) to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Shotwell 0.8.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know how to change shortcuts in Shotwell directly but you can use a Gnome feature to do that : "Edit Menu Shortcut Key"

**Activate this feature**

- Run [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) and go to /desktop/gnome/interface/
- Check the 'can_change_accels' option
- no need to restart anything, just close gconf-editor

**Change menu shortcuts in your apps**

- Start your application : Shotwell here
- Place your mouse on the menu you want to change
- Press the key combination : you'll see your shortcut appear in the menu

I don't think you'll be able to set <kbd>R</kbd> as a key shortcut directly with this feature but <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (or <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> ...) should work

Answer (score 2):

As Bubblegum pointed out, GNOME has a generic feature for changing keyboard shortcuts.  You might think that you could use this technique for editing Shotwell's shortcuts.  Unfortunately, if you try to do this you'll see that the shortcuts you assign are lost as soon as you restart Shotwell.  This is a known bug:

http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/2653